# One folder in Windows 7 very slow on SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, performance

I have one folder, in particular my 'Downloads' folder, that windows is struggling to read. It gets there in the end but even sorting the files by date takes a could of minutes. It is only about 500 files and maybe 15 GB total, and is hosted on a new (months old) Samsung SSD.

Any ideas on a diagnosis? It feels perhaps like a corrupt file or two slowing the system down but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried performing a `chkdsk` on the device?

Comment: I have not, will report the results when I do.

Comment: Leave the folder and files in place. Make a new folder somewhere else. Copy the files to the new folder. Are the new file copies in the new folder still slow?

Comment: Before you responded I literally just *moved* half of the files to a subfolder. Both folders were fast. moving them back and the folder is quick again. I will report whether the problem returns.

Comment: Better check the SMART data of the SSD.

Comment: Please let us know what you find

Comment: If I had to guess I suspect your security software is scanning files in there as Explorer maybe opens the files for image resources, etc..  What AV product do you have?  Is it faster when realtime/on-access scanning is disabled?  If you run Process Monitor (Microsoft/Sysinternals) with a path filter for this directory, what processes are "interested" in these files?